# Docker compose issue while building python image, access denied or repository does not exist

Tags: django, linux, docker, docker-compose, docker-multi-stage-build

I am trying to troubleshoot [a tutorial on udemy](https://www.udemy.com/course/detailed-django-rest-api/learn/lecture/31039570#questions/18547228) on Windows 10 but why my compose file is failing to run.  I tried relogging into Docker and I am able to run `Docker build python:3.9-slim-bullseye` successfully.  Does anyone here see my issue and help me understand what is happening?

I think my issue with with the line:

```
apt-get update && apt-get install --no-install-recommends -y \
    build-essential \
    libpq-dev
```

The tutorial's  [original code is here on his github](https://github.com/API-Imperfect/authors-haven-api-live) but most of my code is a straight copy from him.  Here is a [link to the repo](https://github.com/justin107d/author-haven-api) I have of what was covered so far.

**local.yml file**

```
version: "3.9"

services:
  api:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: docker/local/django/Dockerfile
    command: /start
    container_name: django-api
    volumes:
      - .:/app
      - static_volume:/app/staticfiles
      - media_volume:/app/mediafiles
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    env_file:
      - ./.envs/.local/.django
      - ./.envs/.local/.postgres
    depends_on:
      - postgres
      - mailhog
    networks:
      - authors-api-live

  postgres:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./docker/local/postgres/Dockerfile
    container_name: postgres
    # volumes:  # This is also causing issues
    #     - local_postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    #     - local_postgres_data_backups:/backups
    env_file:
        - ./.envs/.local/.postgres
    networks:
        - authors-api-live
    
  mailhog:
    image: mailhog/mailhog:v1.0.0
    container_name: mailhog
    ports:
      - "8025:8025"
    networks:
      - authors-api-live

networks:
  authors-api-live:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
  local_postgres_data_backups: {}
  static_volume:
  media_volume:
```

**Django Dockerfile**

```
ARG PYTHON_VERSION=3.9-slim-bullseye

FROM python:${PYTHON_VERSION} as python

# BUILD STAGE
FROM python as pthyon-build-stage
ARG BUILD_ENVIORMENT=local

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install --no-install-recommends -y \
    build-essential \
    libpq-dev

COPY ./requirements . 

RUN pip wheel --wheel-dir /usr/src/app/wheels \
    -r ${BUILD_ENVIORMENT}.txt


# RUN STAGE
FROM python as python-run-stage

ARG BUILD_ENVIORMENT=local
# ARG APP_HOME=/usr/src/app
ARG APP_HOME=/app

ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1

ENV UNBUFFERED 1

ENV BUILD_ENVIORMENT=${BUILD_ENVIORMENT}

WORKDIR ${APP_HOME}

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install --no-install-recommends -y \
    libpq-dev \
    gettext \
    && apt-get purge -y --auto-remove -o APT::AutoRemove::RecommendsImportant=false \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# use wheels to make installation faster
COPY --from=python-build-stage /usr/src/app/wheels /wheels/

RUN pip install --no-cache-dir --no-index --find-links=/wheels/ /wheels/* \
    && rm -rf /wheels/
    
# Copy in entrypoint to test connection to database
COPY ./docker/local/django/entrypoint /entrypoint
RUN sed -i 's/\r$//g' /entrypoint
RUN chmod +x /entrypoint

# check if models are migrated
COPY ./docker/local/django/start /start
RUN sed -i 's/\r$//g' /start
RUN chmod +x /start

# COPY ./docker/local/django/celery/worker/start /start-celeryworker
# RUN sed -i 's/\r$//g' /start-celeryworker
# RUN chmod +x /start-celeryworker

# COPY ./docker/local/django/celery/flower/start /start-flower
# RUN sed -i 's/\r$//g' /start-flower
# RUN chmod +x /start-flower

COPY . ${APP_HOME}

ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint"]
```

**Error Message:**

```
PS C:\Users\...\MasterDjangoRESTFrameworkWithDocker\authors-haven-api\authors-src> docker-compose -f local.yml up -d --remove-orphans   
Building api
[+] Building 1.2s (9/18)
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                       0.1s 
 => => transferring dockerfile: 32B                                                                                                                        0.0s 
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                          0.1s 
 => => transferring context: 34B                                                                                                                           0.0s 
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/python:3.9-slim-bullseye                                                                                0.0s 
 => [internal] load build context                                                                                                                          0.2s 
 => => transferring context: 5.14kB                                                                                                                        0.1s 
 => [python 1/1] FROM docker.io/library/python:3.9-slim-bullseye                                                                                           0.0s 
 => ERROR FROM docker.io/library/python-build-stage:latest                                                                                                 0.9s
 => => resolve docker.io/library/python-build-stage:latest                                                                                                 0.9s 
 => CACHED [python-run-stage  1/11] WORKDIR /app                                                                                                           0.0s 
 => CANCELED [python-run-stage  2/11] RUN apt-get update && apt-get install --no-install-recommends -y     libpq-dev     gettext     && apt-get purge -y   1.0s 
 => [auth] library/python-build-stage:pull token for registry-1.docker.io                                                                                  0.0s 
------
 > FROM docker.io/library/python-build-stage:latest:
------
failed to load cache key: pull access denied, repository does not exist or may require authorization: server message: insufficient_scope: authorization failed  
ERROR: Service 'api' failed to build : Build failed
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like there's a typo on the line where you're assigning the build stage name.

```
FROM python as pthyon-build-stage
```

Change this to:

```
FROM python as python-build-stage
```

and the build stage should be named as expected for later stages.